# Vue.js - Preventing dblclick event in parent element

Tags: vue.js

Hi I am new in learning Vue.js and I was wondering if I can prevent dblclick event in parent element if I double click child element. .stop or .prevent did not work. Deleting span tag is the same.

```
    <div @dblclick="$emit('someEvent', task.id)">
            <span>
                {{task.text}}
                <i @click.stop="$emit('set-task-to-edit', task.id)"></i>
            </span>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The click event ([mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/click_event)) and the dblclick event ([mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/dblclick_event)) are two separate events. Stopping one event from bubbling does nothing to the other event.

To properly stop the double click event from escaping the child, you also need to define a double click event handler for the child that stops the event from bubbling up. You don't need to define a handler, because you are not doing anything with the event. Just using `@dblclick.stop` does the trick.

```
    <div @dblclick="$emit('someEvent', task.id)">
            <span>
                {{task.text}}
                <i @dblclick.stop @click.stop="$emit('set-task-to-edit', task.id)"></i>
            </span>
    </div>
```

On a side note, you mention that you tried both `.stop` and `.prevent`. `.stop` is to stop that specific event from bubbling to parent elements. `.prevent` stops the browser from doing what it normally does for such an event (e.g. opening a link).

[image: Edit Prevent double click from bubbling up to parent]